# Call Sinatra erb from another class

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I need to render a Sinatra erb template inside a class in my controller.  I'm having issues calling this though.  I've looked in the Sinatra rdocs and have come up with this:

```
Sinatra::Templates.erb :template_to_render
```

When I do this, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `erb' for Sinatra::Templates:Module
```

Is there a way to call this from another class?

Comment: any answer on this yet?

Answer (score 1):

To imitate rendering behavior of Sinatra controller in some other class (not controller) you can create module like this:

```
module ErbRender

  include Sinatra::Templates
  include Sinatra::Helpers
  include Sinatra::ContentFor

  def settings
    @settings ||= begin
      settings = Sinatra::Application.settings
      settings.root = "#{ROOT}/app"
      settings
    end
  end

  def template_cache
    @template_cache ||= Tilt::Cache.new
  end

end
```

*Here you may need to tune `settings.root`*

Usage example:

```
class ArticleIndexingPostBody

  include ErbRender

  def get_body
    erb :'amp/articles/show', layout: :'amp/layout'
  end

end
```

This will properly render templates with layouts including `content_for`

Answer (score 0):

why you don't require 'erb' and after use only erb

```
  ## You'll need to require erb in your app
  require 'erb'

  get '/' do
    erb :index
  end
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work for what I'm doing.  Those instructions are rather old, and do not apply to the current versions of Sinatra.  Ideally, I'd like to use Sinatra's built in erb.

Answer (score 0):

You could have your class return the template name and render it in the main app.

Of course that's not exactly an answer (I don't have enough rep to add a comment with this account) and you're probably doing just that by now anyway...